# LINQ distinct items by Date part only from DateTime field in Select clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling to get the syntax correct for the following.

I'm trying to get a distinct list of optionNames by `date` and not datetime. The following LINQ query gets me the distinct list by datetime only

```
var optionList = await db.OptionsStore.Select(x => new { x.OptionTime, x.OptionName })
.Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

`x.OptionTime` is a DateTime type. I know how to use the date part only in a where clause but not the select clause. Changing x.OptionTime to x.OptionTime.Date gives this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported

Is this possible to convert the datetimes to date in the query or would I need to process it afterwards?

Comment: Why can't you change it to `x.OptionTime.Date`?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé - doing that I get error -`System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported` - I think it believes it's a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` for that (`DateTime.Date` can't be converted to SQL):

```
var optionList = await db.OptionsStore
                         .Select(x => new 
                          { 
                              OptionTime = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.OptionTime), 
                              OptionName = x.OptionName 
                          })
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try the System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions TruncateTime function.